# Custom Borders with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a responsive border similar to this?

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=qyzrys&s=5

I have tried the border-image technique but this fills the png with white as the border is placed inside the div.I have also tried placing a div horizontal to underlying div but it is difficult to know the exact width with % + padding/margins.

Any help/ideas on achieving this would be appreciated?

Comment: please post your code in jsfiddle to help you easily.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JT3E7/

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 2):

Border images are overlaid on top of the element so even if your border image is transparent it will still show the color of the element behind it.

A pure CSS solution to this would be to use a pseudo-element.

First set the position of your div to non-static (relative, absolute, or fixed will work).
Then make your element absolute and span the width of the div:

```
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/PEY43VD.png);
}
```

This will take in consideration whatever width/padding your div has.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jDau2/

Comment: the problem remains the same border-image: not to slice triangle when window resized. You need then to set via media-queries steps by steps with max-width tuned up on screen width. this could be done recursvly with javascript to readapted width at any time. (div.width/img.width)

Comment: i used your image for the translucid border-image :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEfGx thx for him :)

Comment: @GCyrillus, that's true but that wasn't a requirement in the original question, he only wanted there to be a transparent background behind his border. But yes, if you want to ensure triangles aren't sliced media queries can address this.

Comment: i still do read "responsive" , wich means width has to adapted to screen width somehow, no ? i did not understand he did not know how to set a border-image :). I might mistake (as often) though, since english is not my mother language

Comment: @GCyrilus Good point +1

Comment: hey guys thanks for the responses on this, the pseudo-element div works really well

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-image from a png image with translucid background instead the gradient.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iFJpH

```
html {background:lightgray;}
div {margin:5em;min-height:5em;background:white;border-style: solid;
border-width: 40px 10px 0px;
-moz-border-image: url(http://oi44.tinypic.com/qyzrys.jpg) 34 18 1 29 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(http://oi44.tinypic.com/qyzrys.jpg) 34 18 1 29 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(http://oi44.tinypic.com/qyzrys.jpg) 34 18 1 29 repeat;
border-image: url(http://oi44.tinypic.com/qyzrys.jpg) 34 18 1 29 repeat;
```

with even online tool : http://border-image.com/

Responsive ?
Last thing to do to tune it,
 it is to set different max-width via mediaqueries
so, triangles don't get sliced when window reduces width.
You can as well set border-size to grow or reduce triangles. they will strectch

Comment: a fork with image of @Alex D , to show idea from png image : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEfGx as border-image.

Comment: Good solution! The only thing I don't like about it is it requires an additional div in the markup just for style. Ideally style should exist solely in CSS.

Comment: this div is for content purpose and holding background, else background shows under borders too :) This div could be a <p> or <section><article> whatever you do really need in your structure. (div are neutral and can be used for this as holding some 'id' or specific 'class' , 'data-attributes' for script purpose or CSS sibbling. Choices are up to you anyhow :)

Comment: I tried this solution with the border image and found that it clashed with my box shadow as the shadow was applied to the border image, but this works really well on divs without the box shadow.I used the following css so that i could use a png a avoid the white background -  
-background-clip:padding;

Comment: perfect, what about other browser :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is (I have) two kind of solution for you. 
    1. In the case, there is no matter for you to have your bordered  div  in the same color than your page, you can just make it transparent.
    2. In the case the first solution is not convenient for you, try this:

```
For the css:

div
{
  border:15px solid transparent;
  width:500px;  //As you want
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);  //No padding here ;)
}
#NiceBorder
{
 -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 round;
 -o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 round;
 border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 round;
}


For the html:

<div id="NiceBorder" style="margin: 0 ; width: auto;">
     <div style="margin: auto ; width: auto; background-color: #000;">
        Here, you can put some background-color as you want and that's it.
        I hope I've helped you.  
     </div>
</div>
```

Lionnel.